# Recursively convert all keys in a multi-dimensional array to snake_case

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array, key, camelcasing

I am trying to convert the keys of a multi-dimensional array from camelCase or StudlyCase/PascalCase to snake_case, with the added complication that some keys have a leading exclamation mark that I'd like to be removed.

For example:

```
$array = array(
  '!AccountNumber' => '00000000',
  'Address' => array(
    '!Line1' => '10 High Street',
    '!line2' => 'London'));
```

I would like to convert to:

```
$array = array(
  'account_number' => '00000000',
  'address' => array(
    'line1' => '10 High Street',
    'line2' => 'London'));
```

My real-life array is huge and goes many levels deep.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the modified function I have used, taken from soulmerge's response:

```
function transformKeys(&$array)
{
  foreach (array_keys($array) as $key):
    # Working with references here to avoid copying the value,
    # since you said your data is quite large.
    $value = &$array[$key];
    unset($array[$key]);
    # This is what you actually want to do with your keys:
    #  - remove exclamation marks at the front
    #  - camelCase to snake_case
    $transformedKey = strtolower(preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1_$2', ltrim($key, '!')));
    # Work recursively
    if (is_array($value)) transformKeys($value);
    # Store with new key
    $array[$transformedKey] = $value;      
    # Do not forget to unset references!
    unset($value);
  endforeach;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a more generalized version of Aaron's. This way you can just plug the function you want to be operated on for all keys. I assumed a static class.

```
public static function toCamelCase ($string) {
  $string_ = str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('_',' ', $string)));
  return lcfirst($string_);
}

public static function toUnderscore ($string) {
  return strtolower(preg_replace('/([^A-Z])([A-Z])/', "$1_$2", $string));
}

// http://stackoverflow.com/a/1444929/632495
function transformKeys($transform, &$array) {
  foreach (array_keys($array) as $key):
    # Working with references here to avoid copying the value,
    # since you said your data is quite large.
    $value = &$array[$key];
    unset($array[$key]);
    # This is what you actually want to do with your keys:
    #  - remove exclamation marks at the front
    #  - camelCase to snake_case
    $transformedKey = call_user_func($transform, $key);
    # Work recursively
    if (is_array($value)) self::transformKeys($transform, $value);
    # Store with new key
    $array[$transformedKey] = $value;
    # Do not forget to unset references!
    unset($value);
  endforeach;
}

public static function keysToCamelCase ($array) {
  self::transformKeys(['self', 'toCamelCase'], $array);
  return $array;
}

public static function keysToUnderscore ($array) {
  self::transformKeys(['self', 'toUnderscore'], $array);
  return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run a foreach on the arrays keys, this way you'll rename the keys in-place:

```
function transformKeys(&$array) {
    foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
        # This is what you actually want to do with your keys:
        #  - remove exclamation marks at the front
        #  - camelCase to snake_case
        $transformedKey = ltrim($key, '!');
        $transformedKey = strtolower($transformedKey[0] . preg_replace('/[A-Z]/', '_$0', substr($transformedKey, 1)));
        # Store with new key
        $array[$transformedKey] = &$array[$key];
        unset($array[$key]);
        # Work recursively
        if (is_array($array[$transformedKey])) {
            transformKeys($array[$transformedKey]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's put me in the right direction but there were a couple of issues.

First of all the $transformedKey was spitting out some odd results so I have slightly modified that line. Also the recursive if statement needs to be positioned above the line storing the new array key for some reason.

I'll post my modified function below.

Comment: Just noticed, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Although this may not be an exact answer to the question, but I wanted to post it here for people who are searching for elegant solution for changing key case in multidimensional PHP arrays. You can also adapt it for changing array keys in general. Just call a different function instead of array_change_key_case_recursive

```
// converts all keys in a multidimensional array to lower or upper case
function array_change_key_case_recursive($arr, $case=CASE_LOWER)
{
  return array_map(function($item)use($case){
    if(is_array($item))
        $item = array_change_key_case_recursive($item, $case);
    return $item;
  },array_change_key_case($arr, $case));
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to a different question. Please only post answers which specifically resolve the asked question. It doesn't make sense to be able to earn points and potentially displace other correct answers while not satisfying the queation requirements. If this exact question doesn't exist on Stack Overflow, please post a new question, then self-answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function like:

```
   function convertToCamelCase($array){

           $finalArray     =       array();

           foreach ($array as $key=>$value):

                    if(strpos($key, "_"))
                            $key                    =       lcfirst(str_replace("_", "", ucwords($key, "_"))); //let's convert key into camelCase


                    if(!is_array($value))
                            $finalArray[$key]       =       $value;
                    else
                            $finalArray[$key]       =       $this->_convertToCamelCase($value );
            endforeach;

            return $finalArray;
}
```

and call this like:

```
$newArray = convertToCamelCase($array);
```

for working example [see this](https://github.com/abhinavbhardwaj/PHP/blob/master/ConvertArrayintoCamelCase/example.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

class Maison {
    
    public $superficieAll_1;
    public $addressBook;
    
}

class Address { 
    public $latitudeAmi;
    public $longitude;
}

$maison = new Maison();
$maison->superficieAll_1 = 80;
$maison->addressBook->longitudeAmi = 2;
$maison->addressBook->latitude = 4;

$returnedArray = transformation($maison);
print_r($returnedArray);

function transformation($obj){
    //object to array
    $array = json_decode(json_encode((array) $obj),true);
    //now transform all array keys
    return transformKeys($array);
}    

function transformKeys($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        // echo "$key <br>";
        unset($array[$key]);
        $transformedKey = strtolower(preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1_$2', ltrim($key, '!')));
        $array[$transformedKey] = $value;  
        // echo "$transformedKey update <br>";
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $array[$transformedKey] = transformKeys($value);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you would have to write a function to copy the array (one level) and have that function call itself if any of the values is an array (a recursive function).

- The exclamation marks are easily removed using trim()
- The underscore before the uppercase characters in the middle can be added using a regex
- After adding the underscore, the whole key can be converted to lower case

What exactly do you need any specific help with?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid mutating the original array and return a new array with reformatted keys, use a recursive function without modifying by reference and return the new array on every level.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gmGTe))

```
function snakeCaseKeys($array): array
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        $k = strtolower(
                 preg_replace(
                     '/[a-z]\K(?=[A-Z])/',
                     '_',
                     ltrim($k, '!')
                 )
             );
        $result[$k] = is_array($v) ? snakeCaseKeys($v) : $v;
    }
    return $result;
}

var_export(
    snakeCaseKeys($array)
);
```

Or mutate each level in place without generating a new array: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/j3dlJ))

```
function snakeCaseKeys($array): array
{
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        unset($array[$k]);
        $k = strtolower(
                 preg_replace(
                     '/[a-z]\K(?=[A-Z])/',
                     '_',
                     ltrim($k, '!')
                 )
             );
        $array[$k] = is_array($v) ? snakeCaseKeys($v) : $v;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Test data:

```
$array = [
    '!AccountNumber' => '00000000',
    'Address' => [
        '!Line1' => '10 High Street',
        'deeperSubArrayToRekey' => [
            'camelCase' => 'starts with lowercase',
            'PascalCase' => 'starts with uppercase',
            'StudlyCase' => 'is a synonym for PascalCase',
            '!!!!snake_case' => 'is already fully lowercase',
        ],
        '!line2' => 'London',
        'Line1' => 'will overwrite 10 High Street',
    ]
];
```

Output:

```
array (
  'account_number' => '00000000',
  'address' => 
  array (
    'line1' => 'will overwrite 10 High Street',
    'deeper_sub_array_to_rekey' => 
    array (
      'camel_case' => 'starts with lowercase',
      'pascal_case' => 'starts with uppercase',
      'studly_case' => 'is a synonym for PascalCase',
      'snake_case' => 'is already fully lowercase',
    ),
    'line2' => 'London',
  ),
)
```

Even if modification by reference is used (like in aaronrussell's answer), the foreach loop is still creating copies of data and new keys still have to be generated and old keys destroyed -- there is no shortcut to modify keys in-place.