# How do I use array_change_key_case() in PHP to change the key case in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

My multidimensional arrays are

```
$input_array = array(
    array(
        'First' => 1,
        'Third' => 3
    ),
    'Second' => 2,
    'Fourth' => 4
);

$another_array = array(
    'First' => array(
        'Third' => 3,
        'Fifth' => 5
    ),
    'Second' => 2,
    'Fourth' => 4
);
```

How can I change the key case of these two multidimensional arrays using `array_change_key_case()` in PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert all keys in a multi-dimenional array to snake\_case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444484/how-to-convert-all-keys-in-a-multi-dimenional-array-to-snake-case)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting keys of an array/object-tree to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981458/converting-keys-of-an-array-object-tree-to-lowercase)

Answer (score 2):

Find answer here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php#114914

```
function array_change_key_case_recursive($arr)
{
    return array_map(function($item){
        if(is_array($item))
            $item = array_change_key_case_recursive($item);
        return $item;
    },array_change_key_case($arr));
}

$input_array = array(array('First'=>1,'Third'=>3),'Second'=>2,'Fourth'=>4);

return array_change_key_case_recursive($input_array);
```

Try demo https://implode.io/LCW5CG